# Is It possible to write in the same line and don't write in several row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, psutil

I would print the cpu usage with this simple python script. I would write the result, erase that row and re-write on the same line as like as windows shell does with some commands. Is it possible?

```
import psutil                                     #import tsutil
import time

def printit():
    while(1):
        print(psutil.cpu_percent())
        time.sleep(3)
printit()
```

This print line per line. I would the result always change on the same line

Comment: use ```print('text content', end='')```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use carriage return on print function

```
import psutil
import time
import sys

def printit():
    while(1):
        print('{:06.2f}'.format(psutil.cpu_percent()), end='\r')
        time.sleep(3)
printit()
```

*Updating: Using \r will break if the strings differ on size, format can fix this*

Answer (score 1):

yes, use `print(psutil.cpu_percent(), end=' ')`

you also need to flush stdout, because the content won't actaully be printed on screen unless you print a newline char.

try this:

```py
import psutil
import time
import sys

def printit():
    while(1):
        print(psutil.cpu_percent(), end=' ')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(3)
printit()
```